# Row numbering in iOS SQLite

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, numbers, row

In an SQLite table in my app, I need to have a column with row numbers going 1,2,3,4,5 (or to be able to get a row number for every row). Now I delete rows and add rows all the time, so I cant just put a number every time I add a new row, because when rows are deleted, the numbering will get messed up. So is there a way to get the row number, or create a special column that will act as row numbering? If so, how?

Comment: Do you want, for example, have 1,2,3,4,5 rows, and when you delete row 4, the row 5 would now hold the number 4, or that the rows would now be 1,2,3,5?

Comment: yes when i delete row 4, than row 5 becomes 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want this to be reset every time you add and delete rows, should this really be a column in your table?

For example, if you just want to be able to select the 20th row from the table, you can use the `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` clauses of SQL to select a particular row, e.g., to retrieve the 20th row from my `news` table, I could do:

```
SELECT * FROM news LIMIT 1 OFFSET 19;
```

Alternatively, if you really want a column with this row number information, you could just add a new `INTEGER` column type and then write an Objective C method to update the values for that column, and invoke that method any time you delete or insert rows in your result set.

There are a number of ways of solving your problem. You have to explain what you're trying to accomplish for us to help you out. The typical `AUTOINCREMENT` answer is what we generally use for table keys, but it sounds like you don't want this to be the key of your table, but rather something else.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [ROWID](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) which is an auto-incrementing number, you can compute row numbers by selecting all of your data, ordered by ROWID and then using their index in the returned results as their row number. If you have some data model class you're creating, you could pass that in to its initializer.

If that won't do what you want, then how about adding some more details about what you're trying to do. Are you sure you need a row number?

Comment: How can i make an auto-incrementing ROWID, would it be affected by deleting a row?

Comment: and well i am trying to create a table of 'friends' and sort them by the time of connection (so obviously a row # 1 will be the first friend created, and row #2 will be the second friend created and so on....

Comment: If it's by time of connection, you should store the time and sort by it. That will ensure you've always got them in the correct order. (And again use their index in the array you get from the db as their row number.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to go changing all the existing records in your database when you delete rows that make "holes" in your row-umber scheme.

SQLite already supports what you want, with the ROWID.  When you make a select query, just specify it to sort on ROWID, and all your returned records will be sorted in their proper order, and you can iterate over them in their order.

See this page: http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

FWIW, there are certainly places where you should prefer direct SQLite over Core Data.  However, those are rare cases.  In general, reach for Core Data first, and fall back to SQLite only when CD does not serve your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Just use an autoincrement primary key for the table. then there is always a unique identifier you can access a record.

Comment: in that case you should ask yourself if the additional effort is it worth. alternatively you can use a second field with just that kind of numbers. so you are then able to use the uid's for db operations and the other field for doing some other things who doesn't need to be so restrictive.